# How to query order to asc (or desc) when column format is varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `product(ID, name, quanlity)` with quanlity is `varchar(55)`

With my data

```
1 | Iphone 3  | 7
2 | Iphone 3S | 8
3 | Iphone 4  | 79
4 | Iphone 4S | 9
5 | Iphone 5  | 10
```

And my query:

```
Select * From product order by quanlity DESC
```

But result can't order quanlity, because quanlity is varchar, How to query sort exactly

```
    4 | Iphone 4S | 9
    2 | Iphone 3S | 8
    3 | Iphone 4  | 79
    1 | Iphone 3  | 7    
    5 | Iphone 5  | 10
```

Comment: why have you kept `quanlity` column as varchar?

Comment: rename your columns for god sake

Answer (score 3):

Not an elegant method, but you can cast the column to integer

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY CAST(quanlity AS UNSIGNED)
```

Note: You are going to hit performance issue and unexpected order when you have something which is not integer. I suggest you better change the column type to integer (if it is possible -even with some trouble)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `product ` ORDER BY convert(`quanlity`, decimal) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can CAST the column to a different type to allow for a natural numeric sort:

```
SELECT * FROM `product ` ORDER BY CAST(`quanlity` AS unsigned)
```